# SQL Server: восстановить mdf

Tags: sql-server

Есть база данных в SQL Server, состоящая из двух файлов ldf и mdf. Если mdf файл поврежден, то возможно восстановить mdf из ldf и как это сделать?

Comment: Есть полный бэкап базы (пусть даже старый) до повреждения? База доступна в SQL Server, или совсем убита?

Comment: Специальной бэкап не делали. Есть только ldf и mdf файлы, которые были изначально. Потом в базу добавлялись данные. Но недавно выяснили, что флешка на которой были эти файлы, повредилась вместе с mdf.

Answer (score 2):

Можно скриптом.

```
CREATE DATABASE DataBaseName
ON ( FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Northwind.mdf' )
LOG ON ( FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Northwind_log.ldf')
GO
```

Поменяйте пути:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

Укажите папку, в которой находятся ваши файлы.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я знаю (могу ошибаться) встроенных средств для восстановления базы из LDF без наличия Full Backup нет.

Из невстроенных - есть утилиты, превращающие LDF - лог транзакций - в последовательность SQL-команд для выполнения этих транзакций.

Это умеют делать

- [Apex SQL Log](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/open-ldf-file-and-view-ldf-file-content/) - платный.
- [LDF File Viewer](http://www.freeviewer.org/ldf/) - тоже платный, несмотря на домен - но может быть вам хватит бесплатной версии.
- [LiteSpeed’s Transaction Log Reader](http://documents.software.dell.com/litespeed-for-sql-server/7.5/netvault-litespeed-for-sql-server-log-shipping-guide/log-reader-read-transaction-logs)  - платный, не уверен, умеет ли работать именно с ldf, но точно умеет с trn.