# Как восстановить БД MS SQL из битого ldf и full backup?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recovery

*Кратко о причинах - проблемы с хранилищем привели к потере файла БД. Все.*

Проверено - файла базы mdf - нет. Лог ldf есть, модель - full.
Есть full backup. Почти свежий, от 09.2016 но имея лог от 14.10.2016, хотелось бы свежее.

**Что попытался сделать сам:**

1. Создал бэкап сохранившегося лога:
   Создал базу KA на другом сервере, `ALTER DATABASE [KA] SET OFFLINE`. удалил файлы, залил свой ka_log.ldf
   `ALTER DATABASE [KA] SET ONLINE`, получил свой `Unable to open the physical file` mdf и т.д.
   сделал `BACKUP LOG [ka] TO DISK = N'D:\Tail.bak' WITH NO_TRUNCATE;`

*Во время бэкапа было видно, что логу тоже досталось в момент падения хоста - было сообщение `BACKUP WITH CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR успешно сформировал резервную копию поврежденной базы данных. Дополнительные сведения об обнаруженных ошибках см. в журнале ошибок SQL Server.` 
В журнале - `Backup detected log corruption in database ka. Context is Bad Middle Sector`*

2. Восстановил базу из имеющегося бк - `RESTORE DATABASE [ka] FROM DISK = N'C:\2016.Bak' WITH NORECOVERY, REPLACE`
3. Попытался вернуть лог - `RESTORE LOG [ka] FROM DISK = N'D:\Tail.bak' WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 1, NORECOVERY, CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR`

Результат - Произошла ошибка во время обработки журнала для базы данных "ka". Если возможно, восстановите из резервной копии. Если резервная копия недоступна, возможно, понадобится перестроить журнал.

Все. В этом месте я кончился. Нутром чувствую, что должен быть какой-то способ добраться до данных, но не пойму как.

Перестроить лог не могу - я сижу в рекавери стейт. Выйти из рекавери не могу - у меня проблемы с восстановленным журналом транзакций.

Answer (score 2):

Если восстановление журнала с `CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR` (либо со `STOP_ON_ERROR`)

```
RESTORE LOG [ka]
    FROM DISK = N'D:\Tail.bak'
    WITH FILE = 1, CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR, NORECOVERY
GO
```

завершается с ошибкой, после которой невозможно выполнить

```
RESTORE DATABASE [ka]
    WITH RECOVERY
GO
```

то можно попытаться восстановиться до какого-то *LSN* в журнале (максимально возможного), при котором `RESTORE LOG` ещё не вызывает ошибок.

Для этого читаем заголовки бэкапов БД и журнала

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = N'C:\2016.Bak'
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = N'D:\Tail.bak'
```

в которых сверяем значения столбцов `FirstLSN` и `LastLSN` (убеждаемся, что цепочка LSN не разорвана, и в журнале действительно есть дополнительная информация).

Допустим, получили:

```
C:\2016.Bak
FirstLSN          LastLSN          
----------------- -----------------
64000000005600195 64000000017600001

D:\Tail.bak
FirstLSN          LastLSN          
----------------- -----------------
64000000005600195 66000000025600001
```

сравниваем LSN: *64000000005600195 <= 64000000017600001 < 66000000025600001* - OK.

Значение `LastLSN` из заголовка БД (равное *64000000017600001*) переводим из десятичного представления в двоичное (см. [здесь](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/886839), функция `fn_convertnumericlsntobinary`), получаем *00000040:000000B0:0001*.

Теперь с помощью `sys.fn_dump_dblog` читаем последовательность LSN из дампа лога (можно отфильтровать только операции завершения транзакций `Operation = 'LOP_COMMIT_XACT'`):

```
select [Current LSN]
from sys.fn_dump_dblog(
    NULL, NULL, N'DISK', 1, N'D:\Tail.bak',
    default, default, default, default, default, default, default,
    default, default, default, default, default, default, default,
    default, default, default, default, default, default, default,
    default, default, default, default, default, default, default,
    default, default, default, default, default, default, default,
    default, default, default, default, default, default, default,
    default, default, default, default, default, default, default,
    default, default, default, default, default, default, default,
    default, default, default, default, default, default, default)
where Operation = 'LOP_COMMIT_XACT';
```

Допустим, получили, следующий список:

```
Current LSN
-----------------------
00000040:000000a0:0002
00000040:000000b8:0001   <-- сначала восстанавливаем журнал к этой отметке
00000040:000000c8:000b   <-- потом к этой
00000040:000000d0:000a   <-- ...
00000040:000000d8:000a   <-- ...
00000040:000000e0:000a   <-- ...
00000040:000000e8:000a   <-- ...
00000040:000000f0:000b   <-- ...
00000040:000000f8:0010   <-- ...
00000040:000000f8:0021   <-- и т.д, пока не встретим ошибку
00000040:000000f8:0027   <-- ERROR
00000040:00000110:0017
00000040:00000130:001b
00000040:00000130:001d
00000040:00000140:000a
```

Заново инициализируем восстановление:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [ka]
    FROM DISK = N'D:\2016.bak'
    WITH NORECOVERY, REPLACE
GO
```

Теперь берём из списка первое значение LSN, которое следует позднее, чем `LastLSN` в бэкапе БД (позднее чем `00000040:000000B0:0001`) и делаем `RESTORE LOG` к этой отметке:

```
RESTORE LOG [ka]
    FROM DISK = N'D:\Tail.bak'
    WITH FILE = 1, STOPATMARK = 'lsn:0x00000040:000000b8:0001', NORECOVERY
GO
```

Если операция прошла без ошибок, повторяем то же самое для следующей отметки, и т.д., пока не дойдём до отметки, восстановление к которой будет вызывать ошибку.

Если отметок много, то можно применить дихотомический поиск, учитывая, однако, что при движении вперёд достаточно выполнять лишь `RESTORE LOG` к новой отметке, но если необходимо вернуться назад, то цепочку восстановления нужно выполнять заново (`RESTORE DATABASE ... WITH REPLACE ...`, затем `RESTORE LOG ...` к нужной отметке).

После того как последняя не вызвавшая ошибку отметка определена, заново восстановим БД и журнал до этой отметки:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [ka]
    FROM DISK = N'D:\2016.bak'
    WITH NORECOVERY, REPLACE
GO
RESTORE LOG [ka]
    FROM DISK = N'D:\Tail.bak'
    WITH STOPATMARK = 'lsn:0x00000040:000000f8:0021', NORECOVERY
GO
```

После чего завершаем восстановление:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [ka]
    WITH RECOVERY
GO
```

Comment: Да я бы с радостью ушел в `EMERGENCY', если бы в рекавери стейт мне было можно выполнить хоть какой-нибудь 'ALTER DATABASE'.

Comment: Добавлю (рано Enter нажал), что dbcc rebuild_log забанен, для перестроения отдельно лога также теперь нужно `ALTER DATABASE <dbname> REBUILD LOG`. А уж DBCC CHECKDB для меня вообще недостижимае мечта :(

А как раз RESTORE WITH RECOVERY не выпускает, предлагает перестроить лог :(

Comment: И теперь, когда я наконец дочитал ответ до конца :) необходимо добавить, что `RESTORE LOG ... WITH STOPATMARK=...` тоже не срабатывает. 

Эта зараза (2014) в ЛЮБОМ случае доходит до конца файла и дает тот же результат, даже если я указываю LSN, который УЖЕ ЕСТЬ в восстановленом полном бэкапе

Comment: @Anatoly, я попробовал смоделировать ситуацию. Создал БД, в ней таблицу, вставил 1000 строк, забэкапил, вставил ещё пару-тройку тысяч строк, перевёл в оффлайн, грохнул mdf, подпортил лог в серединке. Затем БД обратно в онлайн, бэкап хвоста, восстановление БД, восстановление лога с `CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR` и `STOP_ON_ERROR` не прошло - ошибки примерно как у вас и застревание в состоянии восстановления, из которого никуда не дёрнуться.

Comment: @Anatoly Однако восстановление к определённому LSN сработало (правда не к самому последнему, который я смог выцепить из дампа лога). После чего я смог прочесть какие-то строки, которые были вставлены уже после бэкапа БД.

Comment: @Anatoly, что у вас возвращают команды `RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = N'C:\2016.Bak'` и `RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = N'D:\Tail.bak'` (интересуют значения столбцов `FirstLSN` и `LastLSN`)?

Comment: голова  1042000006264000048 и 1042000006266200001

Comment: лог 960000000037600107 и 1064000364507200001

Comment: Причем сервер, по-видимому, просто не обрабатывает лог инкрементно? Восстановление до 1042000006266200001 он пишет, что "Уже выполнен накат всей базы данных или ее части за эту точку."
`RESTORE LOG [ka] FROM  DISK = N'D:\Tail.bak' WITH  NORECOVERY,  STOPATMARK = 'lsn:1042000006266200002'` выдаст  нам ту же ошибку, что и полное восстановление - "Произошла ошибка во время обработки журнала для базы данных"

Comment: @Anatoly, а перед выполнением `RESTORE LOG [ka] FROM DISK = N'D:\Tail.bak' WITH NORECOVERY, STOPATMARK = 'lsn:1042000006266200002'` вы перестартовали восстановление с помощью `RESTORE DATABASE [ka] FROM DISK = N'C:\2016.Bak' WITH NORECOVERY, REPLACE` ? (я подредактировал ответ, чтобы было понятнее).

Comment: предварительно сообщаю: 
1. да, делаю replace перед каждой новой попыткой
2. про fn_dump_dblog не знал, нужно изучать. 
Но - попытка select top * from fn_dump_dblogсрабатывает, select просто - падает "Произошла ошибка внутренней согласованности. Ошибка сходна с предположением. Обратитесь в службу технической поддержки."

Короче, сейчас порою в этом направлении, результат доложу. Да, может быть, есть какие-нибудь рабочие third party решения для анализа и восстановления самого дампа лога?

Comment: @Anatoly, на тестовой БД у меня `fn_dump_dblog` тоже завершался с ошибкой, но какой-то список LSN всё-таки выдавал, и по ним удавалось продвинуться. Что касается third party решений, то посмотрите [вот этот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/494361/193999) ответ, правда, самому мне пользоваться ими не доводилось.